# Parallel - threads? loops?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

So I have an application that uses Google Earth.  I click a button and a new form pops up.  This form remains up while the user clicks places on Google earth in the main form.  After this form pops up, a loop runs that waits for the user to click "OK" or "Cancel".  Currently, I cannot get any user interaction with the main Google Earth form while the pop up is there.

I'm not even sure the best way to approach it so it's hard to search for something relevant.

Here's what I've tried so far:

This is the first part of the code after the button is pressed that is common to everything below:

```
            Form TotArea = new ASPE.GUI.OptimizationWizard.TotalArea();
            DialogResult dr1 = new DialogResult();
            Thread t = new Thread(() => dr1 = TotArea.ShowDialog());
            t.Start();
            //TotArea.TopMost = true;
            bool firstcall = true;
            dynamic[] polystuff = null;
```

Simply running a while loop after the dialog pops up (I knew this would fail):

```
        while (dr1 != DialogResult.OK & dr1 != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
```

Using "Parallel.For":

```
        Parallel.For(0, 1, i =>
        {
         //do stuff
        });
```

This fails because I don't know how to make it wait for me to click the Dialog boxes.

Using this "Parallel While" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/08/12/9867246.aspx :
            ParallelOptions paralleloptions = new ParallelOptions();

```
        Func<bool> condn = () => (dr1 != DialogResult.OK | dr1 != DialogResult.Cancel);
        Action whilebody = () =>
        {
             //do stuff    
        };
```

And these functions:

```
        While(paralleloptions, condn, whilebody);  
    private static IEnumerable<bool> IterateUntilFalse(Func<bool> condition)
    {
        while (condition()) yield return true;
    }
    public static void While(
ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Func<bool> condition, Action body)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(IterateUntilFalse(condition), parallelOptions,
            ignored => body());
    }
```

And that is completely alien to me, it seems to run so much so quickly that it isn't really in parallel at all.

Can anyone suggest anything here?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you running a busy loop at all? Once you call `ShowDialog`, you'll pause execution of that thread until `ShowDialog` returns (i.e. closing your second form. If you want both forms visible and interactive, just call `Show`

Answer (score 1):

ShowDialog should halt execution until a dialog result is returned.  Because you are showing the dialog in a separate thread, it's not halting your current one.

You can go back to using the Parallel.For and just change your code to this:

```
if (DialogResult.OK == TotArea.ShowDialog())
{
     Parallel.For(0, 1, i =>
     {
          //do stuff
     });
}
```

You could also use Task.Factory if you have to do it in the background:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return TotArea.ShowDialog(); });
task.Wait();
if (task.Result == DialogResult.OK)
{
     Parallel.For(0, 1, i =>
     {
          //do stuff
     });
}
```

Comment: Well one of my problems with Parallel for is I don't know how to control how long it runs with form input.  I believe if I implement your suggestions the TotArea form will not be responsible for the length of iterations the loop runs?

Comment: And it seems as if this suggestion waits for user input before running the loop.  I need the loop to run UNTIL the user clicks OK or Cancel.